# I am using HTC Desire HD A9191. When I place or receive a call my phone speaker is automatically turning ON and navigation is popping on the screen

Tags: settings, navigation

I am using HTC Desire HD A9191. When I place or receive a call my phone speaker is automatically turning ON and for every 10-20 seconds navigation page is popping on the screen. Please help to fix this issue.I am facing problem from 3 weeks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried any method from google for your problem ?

There is a software fix for this , try this :

1. Shutdown the phone, remove the battery, press the power button to discharge the phone. Install the battery again and turn the phone back on as normal.
2. Open the ‘All apps’ menu, open ‘Dock Mode’ press the phones menu button and select ‘Settings’. Un-tick the ‘Auto-launch’ option.
3. Open the phones settings menu. Open ‘Display’ and click on ‘G-Sensor calibration’. Follow the prompts to calibrate the sensor.
4. Open the phones settings menu.
5. Open ‘Sound’. Un-tick ‘Flip for speaker’.

Have you installed any new software or software updates recently? Uninstall the software and check if the issue still exists.

Clear the application cache for the car application.

Install Car Dock Settings from the android store. Using the application un-tick the ‘Enable speaker phone’ option.

Original source :  https://www.itsupportguides.com/htc-android-phones/solved-htc-phone-speakerphone-automatically-on-for-all-calls/

Hope it helps !

Comment: Hi Nilesh Jadav, As I followed the above URL before but the issue is not fixed as 'Dock Mode' is not available in HTC Desire HD A 9191 and I installed  "Install Car Dock Settings from the android store. Using the application un-tick the ‘Enable speaker phone’ option." and did the same but issue is not fixed.**Please help if you have any other ways to fix this issue of shitty bug**

Comment: Well havey tried factory reset ? Also I had seen in other forums that they had used proximity sensor apps to control speaker mode , you try that might it help ! If not then back up your data and factory reset.